# PHP: Calculate a math function f(x) in a string

Tags: php, string, function, math

Is it possible to calculate a math function f(x) that in a string. Something like this:

```
$function = '2x+3';
$x = 4;
math_function($function, $x); //Shoud produce 11
```

I can't find a library for tasks like this on PHP.net or with Google, but I don't think I am the first one that wants this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My standard answer to this question whenever it crops up:

Don't use eval (especially if the formula contains user input) or reinvent the wheel by writing your own formula parser.

Take a look at the [evalMath](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2695-PHP-Safely-evaluate-mathematical-expressions.html) class on PHPClasses. It should do everything that you want in a nice safe sandbox.

Comment: +1...  Building a math formula parser is a great academic problem (since there are many well defined edge-cases which yield to a non-trivial solution).  But in terms of a practical problem, it's not worth the effort since there are tools built for it...

Comment: Wow, that was quick! Thank you very much. I didn't even know the existence of eval()! I will take a look at it.

Comment: I'm confused: You say "Don't use eval" and then advice the use of a class that does exactly that. (Still perfectly valid answer that solves ops problem. So +1, even if the evalMath code makes me want to vomit ;) )

Comment: @edorian - evalMath does NOT use eval! It uses Djikstra's shunting yard to parse the formula onto a stack, then processes operations using standard PHP methods in a controlled sandbox

Comment: Glancing over the source one line read:   eval('$stack->push(' . $fnn . '($op1));'); // perfectly safe eval()   --- And so i was confused. But you're right it _seems_ it doesn't use it for calulation. Thanks

Comment: @edorian - that instance could also be replaced with $r = call_user_func($fnn,$op1);$stack->push($r); which is cleaner than using eval(), and that's not dissimilar to what I did with my own math parser.