# handling a string as PHP

Tags: php, compiler-construction, equation, evaluation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Calculate a math function f(x) in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216858/php-calculate-a-math-function-fx-in-a-string)

I have a little problem. I have a string, such that,

```
$a = '(2+3+4)';
```

How can I handle `$a` such that the output, echo `$a` should be 9 instead of just giving `(2+3+4)`.

Answer (score 3):

If your code is indeed `$a = (2+3+4)`, then `echo` **will** output 9.

It sounds like you have it a string. You could `eval()` that string to get the `9`.

Comment: I have done eval() but it dont

Comment: `eval` is evil blah blah security hole blah blah... there has to be a feature where this is auto-appended to any answer that mentions the unspeakable. :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at php's [Eval function](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.eval.php)

```
$string = "(2+3+4)";
eval('$a = '.$string);
echo $a;
```