# PHP Calculate Math Function by Variable

Tags: php, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Calculate a math function f(x) in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216858/php-calculate-a-math-function-fx-in-a-string)

please anyone help me to solve a math function,
for example i want to solve 3x+2y+4z
the value of the variable should be declared in php,
like $x=4, $y=2, $z=1
i know that there is [PHP: Calculate a math function f(x) in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216858/php-calculate-a-math-function-fx-in-a-string) ,
but is there any simple method ?

Comment: The simple method is to use `eval`. The harder method is to build a parser. See the accepted answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256/equation-expression-parser-with-precedence

Comment: Already answered in [PHP: Calculate a math function f(x) in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216858/php-calculate-a-math-function-fx-in-a-string)

Comment: Why does the other answer not satisfy your question? This is a somewhat complex problem, how much simpler does it need to be?

Comment: exactly; what do you mean with "solve"? Actually the string "3x+2y+4z" you posted is not an equation.
<br />
However, you need a parser (Chomsky type-2 language), create the tree representation of you formula and then proceed with the computations. It's pretty much like a simple compiler...

Comment: Why is it not an equation? Also, this is not answer but a comment.

Comment: equations are of the form f1(x1,...,xN) = f2(y1,...,yN). basically they must provide the sign '='

Comment: Ah, of course, you're right. A "statement" it is. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a simple equation:

```
$val = (3*$x)+(2*$y)+(4*$z)
```